# Powerapps date button not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I've just created a powerapps app connectec to sharepoint. Everything seems fine, with one exception.

The "Date" button does nothing, looks like its just an icon. Did i break something in the app ? (for this field i only changed the default value, nothing else).

[image]

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i found the answer. It apparently does not work in Firefox, but it works on chrome.

Nice support microsoft....ffs...

Comment: I have just tested it in Firefox. Indeed! calendars don't work in Firefox.

Comment: Yep. Its a bit dumb that Microsoft doesnt support all browsers forcing us to use Edge or IE (especially if you work for them).

Comment: yet "Microsoft" Chrome browser works best :D